# Reloading search bar results

Tags: angular, routes

I have created a search bar to search for users in my app. The search bar is located in my navbar and when I'm entering an input and click the search button everything works fine, I am being redirected to my search page and the correct results are displayed. However, after being redirected to my search page, when I try to enter another input in my search bar and click the search button, although the url changes, taking the right input and the page automatically refreshes, the results do not update. I have to manually refresh the page one more time and only after that, the new results are being displayed. Why is that?
This is the code in the navbar component:

```
 members: Member[];

 constructor(private memberService: MembersService)

 search(content: string) {
    this.memberService.search(content).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
      this.members = response;
      console.log(response);
      console.log(content);
    })
  }
```

```
<form class="example ml-2"  style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
        <input id="typeahead-format" name="content" [(ngModel)]="model.content" type="text" class="ml-2 
         form-control" placeholder="Search users"/>
        <button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" (click)="search(model.content)" 
         routerLink="search/{{model.content}}"><em class="fa fa-search"></em></button>
</form>
```

This is the code in my search bar component:

```
export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit {

  content: string;
  members: Member[];

  constructor(private memberService: MembersService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(params);
      this.content = params['content'];
    });

    this.search();
  }

  search() {
    this.memberService.search(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('content')).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
      this.members = response;
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let member of members" style="margin-top:3%; margin-left:5%;">
    <p>Username: {{member.userName}}</p>
    <p>Name: {{member.firstName}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Which ChangeDetectionStrategy are you using for your SearchbarComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the usage of *this.route.snapshot*.
As its name indicates, the snapshot is evaluated once and won't change over time. When you perform your second search, since the current component is the same, Angular does not destroy and create the component again. Instead it reuses the original one (and therefore it does not run ngOnInit a second time).

As a result :

- snapshot never changes (which is why your second search doesn't update the *member* list)
- search method is only ran when you load the component (which is why it works when you refresh the page)

To make your code work, you need to call your search method each time the route changes (i.e in your suscription). This would look like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.content = params['content'];
      this.memberService.search(this.content).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
        this.members = response;
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: You are creating a memory leak every time the params changes, fyi.

Comment: I don't have access to the search service code. I assumed it uses complete(), which should not produce any leak.
If not, we can use pipe(take(1)) on the subscription.

Comment: This is my method in the memberService `search(content: string) {
    return this.http.get<Member[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/search?content=' + content);
  }` and your solution works just fine. Is there a problem causing memory leaks?

Comment: It's good to hear. And since http.get uses complete(), there is no need to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use change detector ref  (you can read here: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)
You have to add to your constructor:

`constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }`

and after you reassign the var you should add (inside the subscriber):

`cd.markForCheck();`

It will "tell" that we have change please refresh the DOM

Comment: I can't vote yet because I don't have 15 reputation score :(. I have pressed the vote button and it says that my feedback has been recorded